# Use Set instead of iterating in List

Tags: set, refactoring

I have to refactor this code by using Sets instead of a combination of List and for loop. As in replace the below code with just a couple lines. But with Sets I cannot check if the elements contain a specific variable, ie the record type. Any other way ?

```
if(queriedRtList.isEmpty() || !theObjectSet.contains(theSobject)){
        if(!theObjectSet.contains(theSobject)) theObjectSet.add(theSobject);
        queriedRtList= New List<RecordType> ([SELECT Id, Name, SobjectType, DeveloperName, IsActive
                                              FROM RecordType
                                              WHERE isActive=TRUE AND SobjectType IN:theObjectSet]);
    }
    
    
    if(queriedRtList!=null)
        for(RecordType theRt:queriedRtList){
            //get the recordType Id by looking at the object name and the rt name
            if(theRt.SobjectType==theSobject && (theRt.DeveloperName==theRtName || theRt.Name==theRtName)){
                theId=theRt.Id;
            }
            
        }
    
    return theId;
}
```

Comment: Could the [`getRecordTypeInfos` methods from Schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) help you out here? You can get the RecordTypeId with the Name or the DeveloperName without the query or the need to iterate over its results.

Comment: Some side notes: (a) You don't need to ask if a set contains a value before adding it; just add it. (b) You don't need to make a new List of a query result; the result is already a List (c) The results of a query are never null, but may be an empty list (which is harmless to iterate over), (d) You already filtered by sObjectType, so you know it will match, (e) if you really wanted to use a query, you could just filter by name, too, and just return the first result.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Describe call instead of a query. It's far simpler:

```
DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = theSObject.getDescribe();
RecordTypeInfo rtInfo = describeResult.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(theRtName);
if(rtInfo == null) {
  rtINfo = describeResult.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get(theRtName);
}
return rtInfo?.getRecordTypeId();
```

It's true that a Set wouldn't be proper in your case, you would want to use a nested map (e.g. `Map<sObjectType, Map<String, RecordType>>`, which you could then parse your RecordType data in to, but this is unnecessary, given you just need a simple describe call.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer